# How do I get 6-sided blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've heard of these before, and yet I can't figure out how to get them. The blocks I want are like the 6-sided piston head block. If you can tell me how to use `/setblock` or `/give` to get those blocks, please tell me. I want to know what the data values are in order to get those. Sometimes when I mess with data values, I get milky potions, odorless potions, and the list goes on. I also DON'T want to get one of those purple and black checkerboard texture blocks.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this isn't possible due to the fact that such blocks don't exist in the game at all.

Comment: @blartmemes some of these blocks do technically exist. All-bark logs are can be setblocked, for example. The piston head block is mentioned on the wiki, but is not accessible in the game (maybe MCEdit can do it).

Comment: Aren't all blocks in minecraft 6 sided? They are cubes after all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only two of these blocks that I know of: All-bark log, and the 6-sided piston head you mentioned.

The [logs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Log#Data_values) are `minecraft:log` with a data value of 3 in 0x4 and 0x8 bit, that is, add 12 to the normal data value of the log to get all-bark.

```
setblock ~1 ~ ~ minecraft:log 13
```

---

The [piston](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piston#Data_values) wiki entry is strange, it talks about `0x0` through `0x7`, which is technically wrong but we can work with it. In actuality bits `0x1` through `0x4` (0-7) determine the piston facing, while `0x8` (`+0/+8`) determines if the piston is extended or not.

That being said, the 6-sided piston head is listed as 6 or 7 (14 or 15 if extended). However, using

```
setblock ~1 ~ ~ minecraft:piston 6
```

results in an error message saying:

> An unknown error has occured while attempting to perform this command

This happens for all combinations of `minecraft:piston` or `minecraft:piston_head` and data values of 6, 7, 14 or 15. Using the give command using this data value gives you a checkerboard block, which works like a piston (Because, like with a regular piston, the data value is changed when the block is placed).

Comment: Thank you for telling me this! I will keep this in mind :)

Comment: `0x0` through `0x7` are equivalent to `0` through `7`. Only `0x8` is indicated as a bit flag. (`0x3` is not a bit...)

Answer (score 0):

Another extremely easy way is with worldedit, (which, by the way, is a full mod now. also, this IS NOT a tutorial on how to install worldedit, just Google it.) just use `//replace <block> log:12` and make ugly log things go from this[image: Tent with ugly protruding log blocks.]
to THIS[image: ![Better looking tent!]
(in this example i used `//replace log log:12`)

Answer (score -1):

For 6 sided piston:Go on to 1.7.10 and do `/setblock ~ ~0 ~ 33 7`

For 6 sided logs:Go onto any version and do `/setblock ~ ~ ~ log 12`

Comment: Your welcome!!!