# Minecraft all logs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been working on servers and such where a block with a log texture on ALL sides would be JUST the thing I need, but I have no idea how to do it! HELP!

Comment: You can use resource packs for this. More info here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Resource_pack . (Not writing an answer cuz I don't know all the details behind it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get 6-sided blocks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233105/how-do-i-get-6-sided-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Damage value of the block determines the facing as well as having bark on all sides. See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wood#Block_data) for relevant values.

For example, the following creates an oak log with bark on all sides:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:log 12
```